# SimpleWebRTC Peer Discovery not working properly

Tags: javascript, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I am using SimpleWebRTC library found here: https://simplewebrtc.com

I got the signal-master running which has STUN/TURN configured properly. It's capable of detecting other peers so I assume STUN/TURN is functional. My problem is that when a peer starts their local video, other peers are not discovering it UNLESS they reload the page. I want it so it is automatically pushed to other peers without the need of reloading the page. I think it has to do with the code below (which I took from the example) but I am not sure.

The reason I have autoRequestMedia to false is because I want users to be able to view the other peers' cameras without having to turn their own devices on (also why I don't have webrtc.joinRoom in the readyToCall event).

Currently, users click on a button and it will trigger the startLocalVideo(); and the video is created in the element. Problem is nothing gets pushed to other peers unless the other peers reload the page. Hope that explains it all, let me know if you need more details.

```
var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
// the id/element dom element that will hold "our" video
localVideoEl: 'localCam',
// the id/element dom element that will hold remote videos
remoteVideosEl: '',
// immediately ask for camera access
autoRequestMedia: false,
autoRemoveVideos: true,
url: 'MY SIGNAL-MASTER URL HERE',
localVideo: {
autoplay: true, // automatically play the video stream on the page
mirror: false, // flip the local video to mirror mode (for UX)
muted: true // mute local video stream to prevent echo
}
});

webrtc.joinRoom('testchannel');

// a peer video has been added
webrtc.on('videoAdded', function (video, peer) {
    console.log('video added', peer);
    var remotes = document.getElementById('remoteCams');
    if (remotes) {
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        container.className = 'videoContainer';
        container.id = 'container_' + webrtc.getDomId(peer);
        container.appendChild(video);
        // suppress contextmenu
        // video.oncontextmenu = function () { return false; };
        remotes.appendChild(container);
    }
});

// a peer video was removed
webrtc.on('videoRemoved', function (video, peer) {
    console.log('video removed ', peer.nick);
    var remotes = document.getElementById('remoteCams');
    var el = document.getElementById(peer ? 'container_' + webrtc.getDomId(peer) : 'localScreenContainer');
    if (remotes && el) {
        remotes.removeChild(el);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the join statement into the readyToCall listener :

```
webrtc.on('readyToCall', function() {
     webrtc.joinRoom('roomname');
})
```

or

put the joinRoom call in a setTimout function.